# add push capability on nativescript with onesignal

Tags: xcode, push-notification, nativescript, onesignal

I'm running into an issue with push notifications using Nativescript and Onesignal

Onesignal keeps telling me the app is missing push notifications in xcode.

[image]

But when I run the app, I do get the 'appname would like to send you notifications' message and under xcode everything seems to be set correctly.

[image]

I tried deleting the platforms folder, rebuilding the app and so on, but it remains the same message. When I change the app version, I do see the app version change on the onesignal platform, so the informations is passing but apparently apple does not let the notifications through.

Anyway to debug this? How can I be sure the app has push capabilities?

Comment: One thought, push does not work on simulator.  You have to test on a real device.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, its being tested on real device, even on real life app store app.

Comment: One other note.  Once I made changes to the entitlement file I copied it here:  /app / App_Resources / iOS / so it would be copied each time I did a build.

Comment: did it as well, no luck